# Expected voltage on external gain resistor pre-amp

Tags: switches, gain, preamp

I want to build an amplifier with digitally controlled gain, using the [THAT1510](http://thatcorp.com/datashts/THAT_1510-1512_Datasheet.pdf) pre-amp IC.
The IC provides two pins to set the gain, using resistors.

I want to switch between resistors with analog switching ICs.  In order to choose the right IC, I need do know the maximum voltage I can expect between RG1 and RG2.

Internally, the pre-amp looks like this:

[image: THAT1510 Equivalent Circuit Diagram]

V- being tied to GND and V+ being 36V, what maximum voltage can I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this functional block diagram is a reasonably accurate depiction of the actual internals, all you can say is that the potential at \$R_{G1}\$ will be slightly less than \$-In\$, and \$R_{G2}\$ will be slightly less than \$+In\$.

This is a huge assumption though, and all the things we know about making assumptions are very applicable here.

My preferred approach would be to use a digital potentiometer IC to attenuate the output, like the [MCP45HVX1](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/20005304A-347268.pdf), or use a combination of DAC and voltage-controlled variable gain amplifier.

Suggestion:

Use this amplifier, by all means, but with a much lower supply voltage, so that you widen the range of compatible analogue switches available to you.

Use a second gain stage, with a 36V supply, to further scale up this this small excursion signal to become a larger version that falls within your required extremes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wanted to use switches, because I need high gain accuracy and I only want to use throughhole components.
I could not find any throughhole digital pots. Furthermore they also should be logarithmic... I thought about using the MAX4617 chip, whats your opinion on that?
Do you have any other ideas how simple digital gain control with this chip could work?

The input signal is very low, so I guess RG1 to RG2 will not exceed 5V?

Comment: The only way to know is to try it. Unless you have a really good reason to require an output of 36V in the same stage where you control gain, I think this approach is fraught with problems. Also, your argument "I need precise logarithmic gain control" doesn't at all rule out any other approach. The MAX4617 is fine, if you can keep RG1 and RG2 between its supply potentials. I'll add another suggestion in my answer.

Comment: @helixfoo There are through-hole digital pots, like the MCP41XXX/42XXX from Microchip. But digital pots (whether through-hole or SMT) are noisy and not not very accurate, probably not suitable for sensitive parts of audio circuits.